# Error in resizing Image with the width of the label Java 8.0

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

Hi Guys I'm having issue in my Image, I just want to resize the image w/ my label. By using the filechooser. Here is the code below.

```
  try {

                File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                java.net.URL url = file.toURL();

                BufferedImage imageBuf = null;
                BufferedImage imageSize = null;


                try {
                    imageBuf = ImageIO.read(url);
                    imageSize = (BufferedImage) imageBuf.getScaledInstance(jlbl_image.getWidth(), jlbl_image.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                    ImageIcon img;
                    img = new ImageIcon(imageSize);
                    jlbl_image.setIcon(img);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JFRecordSection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

Here is the error code when I load the image from fileChooser.

```
sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is: your image is **not** a BufferedImage, and so it shouldn't be treated as one. Your assumption is incorrect, however. It's not a that the image loaded from the JFileChooser isn't a BufferedImage, rather it's the ***scaled*** image returned from the `.getScaledInstance(...)` that isn't. So instead cast it to the interface type, `Image`, and you should be able to use it.

Comment: ...or rather, just change the type of `imageSize` to `Image`, do no casting at all, everybody wins. ;-)